How high can oil pressure go on a 737 MAX?
I'm attempting to simulate the EICAS page on the 737 MAX MFD, and I'm researching some limits for the engine based on the FCOM. I've been able to find information at the 737 Tech Site on the lower operating limits for oil pressure, but I didn't find anything talking about how high the pressure can go. I imagine this number should exist somehow, so what would it be? Thanks!

About 41000ft, I'd guess

The 737 does not have an EICAS page, but does have an engine display.  E.g. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74224/what-does-vib-stand-for-in-eicas  Websites which say associate a 737 with EICAS are simply wrong. Are you sure you’re looking at an 737 FCOM?

According to the type certificate data sheet https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/document-library/type-certificates/engine-cs-e/easae115-leap-1b-series-engines there is a minimum oil pressure listed, but no maximum oil pressure listed. Therefore I assume that there is no limit, warning or alarm for too high oil pressure.

@tedioustortoise I think I got the word "EICAS" from the 737 tech site, but my FCOM does not refer to it that way.

It's a Boeing, there is no limit.

There is an upper limit for safe operation that should be mentioned in the FCOM but the highest figure that can be reported is the highest reading the sensor(s) can generate. Finding that would require getting access to the component specifications which are not (AFAIK) in the public domain.

The question is a bit vague. Which pressure exactly would like to know?

The real maximum pressure in normal conditions
The real maximum pressure before some line breaks (if the safety over-pressure valve doesn't work?)
The maximum pressure read by the sensor
The maximum pressure displayed by the screen (which depends on how the EEC interprets the sensor values - it may discard too high values)

1-2-3 are difficult to obtain because only internal Boeing documents have these information. However, if your plan is to simulate the display, you can roughly estimate 4 by just interpolating a real image on the display (assuming linear the graphic). For example:

For 61psi (green line) you have 30px from the yellow line in this image, 27px left, thus doing the propotion you get something around 115-120psi at the top blue line. If you find other images (with better quality) you can redo the calculus and improve the estimation (I assume it should be a "round" number, 115 or 120 are good candidates).
